what device or set of components control battery or AC power?
Just for curiosity, I've always wanted to know what device or component(s) are in charged of handle the power selection in a device that supports: internal rechargeable battery, 6 units of type C 1.5v batteries or (110v AC).

It has no external transformer (i guess it's internal), but if you are using the internal battery or the type C cells and you plug the cable (even without turn it off) it works good, not even a manual selector, is it a relay? an internal "lever" that pushes something?
Just wondering, and no, I have no disassembled it yet, but A LOT of devices i know have the the same principle.

As well as the method mentioned by @Justme you can use a diode from rach of the two voltage sources to the common load. The externally powered supply is designed to provide slightly more than battery max voltage so that it predominates. This has the advantage of mechanical simplicity at the cost of adding a diode voltage drop from each source. The externally powered source can be designed to accommodae this. On a 4 cell battery device and using a Schottky diode you lose about 10 % to 15% of the voltage. ...

Using a MOSFET for the battery switch controlled by the external input voltage reduces the voltage drop when running on battery to essentially zero.

Site rules require an image source citation or link. I have added for an identical image, which appears correct. If you used some other identifiable source please edit your question to add it.

There are different mechanisms obviously, but many devices have a mains input connector which has a mechanical  switch.
If you unplug the mains cord from the unit, the switch connects batteries internally, and if you plug in the mains cord to the unit, it will disconnect the batteries.

Is there any chance where a mechanical failure engaged both sources (AC and batteries) at the same time? Will it BOOOOOOOOM!?

@Panamanian How would I know how your device is built. There is always a chance that a mains powered device (such as phone or laptop charger) or a lithium battery powered device (such as laptop or phone) burns down your house, maybe small but it is non-zero.
